# Controlling time slider using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, time

I am trying to control the time slider object through my code in the python console. As given in couple of examples, the time property of a data frame could be controlled by Data frame time property. Assuming I have a time aware layer on my current document. I just want to control the time slider by specifying the startTime and End time. I had used the below code to change the data frame time.

```
mxd= arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
df.time.startTime= datetime.datetime.strptime('14-JUL-2010 07:45:00','%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df.time.endTime=datetime.datetime.strptime('14-JUL-2010 08:45:00','%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

But the time slider is still showing the intial time Extent of the layer. Is there a way to atleast restrict the layer below with the time property so that i could display only from one time to other time? Typically I have to get user input and run the time slider from that point the user specifies. Please let me know if it is possible in arcpy

Comment: Enhancing ArcPy to support control of Time Slider would make a good ArcGIS Idea - if you submit one be sure to add a link to your original Question

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, you're going to have to do this in ArcObjects. Time-Aware functionality is not fully exposed to ArcPy in 10.0. A solution if you want to continue Python development is to create a time extent-setting executable with ArcObjects and call it from your Python code with time parameters passed into it.
 See this code example from esri:

```
      ITime pStartTime = new TimeClass();
      pStartTime.Year = 2000; pStartTime.Month = 9; pStartTime.Day = 25;
      ITime pEndTime = new TimeClass();
      pEndTime.Year = 2000; pEndTime.Month = 9; pEndTime.Day = 30;

      ITimeExtent pTimeExt = new TimeExtentClass();
      pTimeExt.StartTime = pStartTime;
      pTimeExt.EndTime = pEndTime;
      pTimeDisplay.TimeValue = pTimeExt as ITimeValue;
      pActiveView.Refresh();
```

Source for this snippet: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Sample_Set_the_time_extents_for_a_layer_then_render_the_layer/0001000002nz000000/

You can call an executable in Python using subprocess.call(myexe.exe) http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html